# Is it possible to pass arguments to Symony2 container constructor

Tags: dependency-injection, symfony, containers

When creating an service container in Symfony2 you mostly pass "static" arguments (like other classes etc.) to its constructor.

However I'd like to create a factory and therefore I need to be able to pass an dynamic argument to the service constructor.

The examples I found ( e.g. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/factories.html)  are all ending up using static arguments as argument.

But what do I have to do, if I want my factory to decide which object to return based on (for example) user input?

Answer (score 3):

I have some problems understanding why service factory should not work on your case. Do you need to return different service class unrelated to each other?

What I see from the factory example is that you could do something like this:

```
class NewsletterFactory
{
    public function __constructor(...) 
    {
        // Receive arguments needed to create the service below
    }

    public function get()
    {
        // Say the variable $userInput exists and is derived from constructor
        if ($userInput === 'string') 
            return new NewsletterManager($dynamicArgument1);

        if ($userInput === 'integer') 
            return new AnotherNewsletterManager($dynamicArgument2);

        return new DefaultNewsletterManager();
    }
}
```

Now, if this doesn't fit your needs. You can also create a service say `CustomFactory` that returns what you need. What is returned is not directly a service, so you can do whatever you want. But this would prevent you from requesting the objects created by `CustomFactory` from the dependency container.

Similar to that is the [FormFactory](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormFactory.php). It is the factory used to instantiate form type. But the `FormFactory` is more powerfull since it is coupled with a dependency injection tag and a compiler pass, which register each types into the dependency injection system so they can be retrieved on their own. I don't exactly all the internals of the `Form` component but I think it could solve your problem if other methods do not.

Regards,
Matt